# Binding hierarchical data in sap.m.Panel

Tags: sapui5

I want to achieve something like this.
[image: wireframe for sapui5]

I have created the JSON data for the above structure as follows.

```js
this.oPagePanelModelData = {
  "Pages": [{
    "name": "Page (Analysis)",
    "widgetList": [{
      "name": "Widget 1",
      "infoList": [{
        "label": "title",
        "labelFor": "Title for chart 1"
      }, {
        "label": "description",
        "labelFor": "Description for chart 1"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Widget 2",
      "infoList": [{
        "label": "title",
        "labelFor": "Title for chart 2"
      }, {
        "label": "description",
        "labelFor": "Description for chart 2"
      }, {
        "label": "header2",
        "labelFor": "Header for Chart 2"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Page (Sales Manager Overview)",
    "widgetList": [{}]
  }]
}
```

I am facing problem with binding above data with the controls as shown in the above image.
I have achieved first level of binding as in I get 2 panels (*Page (Analysis)* and *Page (Sales Manager Overview)*). Now I am stuck with how to bind the content of the panel with respect to the data I have. Below is the code I wrote to achieve first level of binding.

```js
this.oPagePanelModel = new JSONModel(); // "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
this.oPagePanelModel.setData(this.oPagePanelModelData);
this.oLayoutForPagePanels = new VerticalLayout(); // "sap/ui/layout/VerticalLayout"
this.oLayoutForPagePanels.setModel(this.oPagePanelModel);
this.oLayoutForPagePanels.bindAggregation("content", {
  path: "/Pages",
  template: this.oPagePanel
});
this.oPagePanel = new Panel({ // "sap/m/Panel"
  expandable: true,
  headerText: "{name}"
});
```

Now in the content of `Panel`, I need to have the structure as the image. I am new to SAPUI5. It seems little cluttered in my mind on how to achieve this. How do I bind contents of `Panel` with the rest of the controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using the below code:

```
<VBox items="{path:'panelModel>/Pages', templateShareable: true}" >
<Panel expandable="true" expanded="false" headerText="{panelModel>name}" width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
    <content>
        <VBox items="{path:'panelModel>widgetList', templateShareable: true}">
            <items>
                <VBox>
                    <Label text="{panelModel>name1}" design="Bold" class="sapUiTinyMargin"/>
                    <VBox items="{path:'panelModel>infoList', templateShareable: true}">
                        <items>
                            <VBox>
                                <Label  text="{panelModel>label}"/>
                                <Input value="{panelModel>labelFor}" />
                            </VBox>
                        </items>
                    </VBox>
                </VBox>
            </items>
        </VBox>
    </content>
</Panel>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a perfect use case scenario for `sap.ui.layout.form.Form`. Below is a snippet from this **sample: [https://embed.plnkr.co/nLXEkzbitSP38GtF/](https://embed.plnkr.co/nLXEkzbitSP38GtF?show=localData%2FdemoData.json,preview)**

```xml
<Page xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
  title="Hierarchical Form Binding in Panel"
  class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding"
  content="{
    path: '/Pages',
    templateShareable: false,
    key: 'name'
  }"
>
  <Panel
    expandable="true"
    expanded="true"
    headerText="{name}"
  >
    <form:Form editable="true" formContainers="{
      path: 'widgetList',
      templateShareable: true
    }">
      <form:FormContainer title="{name}" formElements="{
        path: 'infoList',
        templateShareable: true
      }">
        <form:FormElement label="{label}">
          <Input placeholder="{labelFor}" />
        </form:FormElement>
      </form:FormContainer>
      <form:layout>
        <form:ColumnLayout />
      </form:layout>
    </form:Form>
  </Panel>
</Page>
```

[image: Screenshot portrait]
<sup>Screenshot portrait</sup>

[image: Screenshot wide]
<sup>Screenshot landscape</sup>

From the [API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.Form) reference:

> A `Form` control arranges labels and fields (like input fields) into groups and rows. There are different ways to visualize forms for **different screen sizes**.
>
> A `Form` is structured into `FormContainers`. Each `FormContainer` consists of `FormElements`. The `FormElements` consists of a *label* and the *form fields*. (...)
>
> The `Form` (and its sub-controls) automatically add label and field assignment to enable **screen reader support**. It also adds **keyboard support** to navigate between the fields and groups inside the form.

Compared to other controls, Form adds more semantic values to the DOM, follows Fiori Design guidelines, and provides different types of highly customizable responsive layouts.

---

About `templateShareable`, see the documentation topic *[Lifecycle of Binding Templates](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3a4a9e562988456c9be0ef883ae7da50)*.